# How to Detect Ctrl-z End of File Marker in C Programming Language

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I'm trying to detect whether or not the last byte in a file is control-z [(the MS-DOS originating end of file byte - 0x1A)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z), but I'm not having any success. I'm using

```
fseek(filePointer,-1,SEEK_END);
```

to isolate the last byte and then I'm using

```
fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), sizeof(custom_char), filePointer);
```

to try to read the last byte in.

I'm basically getting garbage when I try to read that byte, and I'm wondering if maybe fread ignores the 0x1A byte by default or if there's any other quirky behavior that people have run across in the past while doing this.

The current logic, which is malfunctioning, is trying to read the last byte and considering the end of file marker found if fread returns 0 (fread should return the number of elements read, right?):

```
if(fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer[0]), sizeof(custom_char), filePointer) == 0)
{
    // strip off the last byte
}
```

edit:
I should add that the problem that I'm having comes up after fopen is called, the BOM is written, and the 3rd byte of the BOM is mistakenly thought to be the 0xA1 end of file marker and stripped off.

Comment: When you invoke `fopen`, do you specify `b` (binary) as part of the `mode` parameter?

Comment: @ChrisW No. I'm reading and writing text files, though. Using the UTF-8 flag.

Comment: Ctrl+Z is an old CP/M convention, required because it could only count sectors, not bytes.  Finding one in a utf-8 encoded file is a dinosaur-and-humans-movie kind of time anachronism.  But yes, fread() already filters it when you open the file in text mode.

Comment: If you're using DOS/Windows, you should mention that in your question. On other systems, stdio normally does not munge your data like that.

Comment: @R.. Sorry about that. You're right. I'm using DOS/Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file on binary mode:

```
FILE *filePointer = fopen("yourfile.txt", "rb");
```

Otherwise file is opened in text mode, which will convert CR-LF char pairs to C '\n' chars, and get rid of EOF char, on Windows/MSDOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my code I'm already inside of conditional statements that make sure that the mode is either "a" or "a+" and not in binary. I'm really just trying to grab the last byte (char) of the file.

Comment: @Stubbs:  Then you'll have to do the detection as a separate step by re-opening the file in binary mode.  This is the correct answer.